# How to create a public google colab notebook for each individual?

Tags: google-colaboratory, public

I would like to create a public Google Colab notebook that people can use to perform a specific calculation, but I am not sure how to create a notebook that is unique to each visitor. In that, I mean that when each person clicks a link, they should be able to use and manipulate the notebook but that should not affect what other users see and do.

An example is the Colab notebook for AlphaFold: https://colab.research.google.com/github/sokrypton/ColabFold/blob/main/AlphaFold2.ipynb. Each person can access this notebook but if one person is working on it, no one else can see what that person is doing.

Hopefully this question makes sense.

Comment: Doesn't using colab require users to have google accounts? Those users will therefore be running their own instances of the notebook...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by default.

As long as your visitors don't have editing permissions their interaction with the notebook won't be visible to other visitors (and editors).

They will see, however, any interactions (namely cell outputs) made by the notebook's editor(s).

Answer (score 0):

[The Answer to your Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmlED.png)

As you see in My SS I attached, all you would have to do, first click the share button on the top right, then click the Restricted dropdown, switch to "**Anyone with the link**", once you click "**Anyone with the link**", click the viewer selection/dropdown, and from then on you can control the amount of power the user accessing the link has, depending on what you want.

Hoped this helped.